# MathJax rendering Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, mathjax

Now I wrote program for Android. This application must render formules to **WebView**, using *MathJax library*. But I have problems... Sometimes it does not work (form time to time)... 
Now source:

```
// This function calls everytime before output

public static void clearWebView()
{
    w.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar", "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\"> <script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
            +"MathJax.Hub.Config({ " 
                +"showMathMenu: false, "
                +"jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], "
                +"extensions: ['tex2jax.js'], " 
                +"TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',"
                  +"'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js', 'MathZoom.js'" +
                "] } "
              +"});</script>"
            +"<script type='text/javascript' "
              +"src=\"file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js\""
              +"></script></head><body><span id='solve'></span></body></html>" ,"text/html","utf-8", "");
    }
```

And two renders functions:

```
public static void RenderHTML(String html)
{       
        w.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('solve').innerHTML += '" + html + "';");

}

public static void RenderMath(String tex)
{
    RenderHTML("\\\\[" + doubleEscapeTeX(tex) + "\\\\]");

    w.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");

}
```

Comment: I am using same code for my app and facing issues on Android 4.4. Its working for me on Android 4.3 and lower.

Comment: Here is the issue i am facing on 4.4 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582282/uncaught-referenceerror-while-loading-asset-file-on-android-4-4

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect solution for 4.4 :

```
  wq.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wq.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            wq.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            wq.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar/", "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
                    +"MathJax.Hub.Config({ "
                    +"showMathMenu: false, "
                    +"jax: ['input/MathML','output/HTML-CSS'], " // output/SVG
                    +"extensions: ['mml2jax.js'], "
                    +"TeX: { extensions: ['noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] }, "
                    //+"'SVG' : { blacker: 30, "
                    // +"styles: { path: { 'shape-rendering': 'crispEdges' } } } "
                    +"});</script>"
                    +"<script type='text/javascript' "
                    +"src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'"
                    +"></script><span id='text'> </span> <span id='math'></span>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");





    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
            {
                wq.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='"
                    + "<math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\">"
                    + "<mstyle displaystyle=\"true\">"
                    + doubleEscapeTeX(questn+ans)
                    + "</mstyle></math>';");
                wq.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
            }
            else
            {
                wq.evaluateJavascript("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='<font color=\"#000000\">`"+doubleEscapeTeX(questn+ans)+"`</font>';",null);
                wq.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
            }
```